# what data format will be considered fastest to be written on Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

WE have various options in Kafka to write data on it,e.g: String format, Byte Array.
What data foramt is considered to be fastest while writing on Kafka.

Moreover do kafka provide any utility to compress whole data once and then write on it.

Also need to consider while consuming the same message we will be de-compressing it, so reading data cost will increase.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka 0.8.2 serialises data as a byte array to its commit log. The `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer` class has the following interface:

```
byte[] serialize(String var1, T var2);
```

It requires a byte array to be returned as the data to be written to the Kafka topic. So the `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer` class currently has to extract the byte array from a String:

```
public byte[] serialize(String topic, String data) {
        try {
            return data == null?null:data.getBytes(this.encoding);
```

So in performance terms if you have binary data then write that to a byte array using the default serializer as creating Strings in Java can be potentially expensive and all Kafka will do is convert your string to a byte array anyway.

Regarding compression Kafka currently offers the following compression [options](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#producerconfigs) on the producer out of the box:

> - compression.codec
> - This parameter allows you to specify the    compression codec for all data generated by this producer. Valid    values are "none",
>     "gzip" and "snappy".

See the following [article](http://nehanarkhede.com/2013/03/28/compression-in-kafka-gzip-or-snappy/) from one of Kafka co-creators but to summarise, GZIP offers the best compression but also requires more CPU cycles. Snappy is a nice compromise and can compress the data and in many cases allows higher throughput. GZIP is better for cross Data Center replication as it requires less bandwidth.

Comment: so, do you say byte[] are fastest to be written on file systems by kafka?oh yes, i will receive data in String format which i am already converting to byte[] as kafka requires. what i want is looking to have this string to have minimum size on the disk to be written after compression/conversion what ever kafka allows.  This i want to achieve to have less time to consume messages when fetched.

Comment: In terms of using String or byte[] for the minimum size on disk, it won't matter. As all data is written as byte[] then even if you use Strings Kafka will serialise this to byte[]. To use the minimum amount of disk use GZIP, although this may not have the performance of snappy - thus if consuming the messages in less time is a priority then use snappy. Disk space is cheap these days so I would go for snappys performance rather than GZIPs superior compression.

Comment: i will look in to kafka compression too, but would it be good to look for performance if we are manually committing consumer offsets, lets say if i have 1 topic with 1 partition and 1 consumer group. means it will have only one consumer instance per partition. Now until and unless 1 message is consumed and committed i cannot fetch next message to process in such case would consumer performance will be neglected or should be taken in care. As next message will be fetched after its being processed and ready for commit as compared to auto commit.

Comment: Kafka by default handles consumer offsets and by default this will not be a bottleneck. Having the topic with a single partition thus making it single threaded would be a bottleneck to performance.